# Why is Firestore access so much slower in my Cloud Functions compared to browser?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a fairly small Firebase app that I'm using to collect some simple data from some friends and create statistics from it. My project setup is a simple webapp hosted in Firebase, Firestore, and Typescript Cloud Functions.

When I attempt to do anything inside the cloud functions that involves accessing the Firestore, queries will take upwards of 10–60 seconds for simple queries, and 1–4 minutes for anything accessing more than ~100 documents. This has been as persistent as it is frustrating, occurring in everything from callable HTTPS functions to pubsub cron jobs.

The craziest part, to me, is when I attempt to do the same functions on the website. A Cloud Function that takes minutes will barely take 100ms when running in the browser.

This leads me to believe that my logic and access patterns are correct (or at least reasonable), but there is an underlying limitation or a critical mistake that I made in my Cloud Functions setup that's causing everything to slow to a crawl.

My desire is to take this app and make it available to more people, but this issue is kneecapping me to a point where I can barely handle a few hundred kilobytes of data from a dozen users.

This problem has been plaguing every cloud function, but the following is the simplest function I have.

In it, I iterate over all users (~10) and grab all documents in their "Plays" collection (~500), then update the user. My project looks as such:

`package.json`

```js
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.1.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "spotify-web-api-node": "^5.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
}
```

`index.ts`

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { firestore } from "firebase-admin";
import { getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
if (!getApps().length) {
    initializeApp();
}

import {recurringFunction, getUserTotals} from "./endpoints";

exports.cronFunc = functions.pubsub.schedule("0 * * * *").onRun(recurringFunction);
// 2 more like this


exports.getUserTotals = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {`
    res.status(200).send("Success");
    getUserTotals();
}
// 5 more like this
```

`endpoints.ts`

```js
export async function getUserTotals() {
    const users = await (await queries.getUsers()).docs;
    users.forEach(async (user) => {
        const allItems = await queries.getAllItems(user.id);
        const total_duration = allItems.docs.map((item) => item.duration).reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
        queries.updateUser(user.id, {
            total_duration,
            total_items: allItems.docs.length,
        });
    });
}
```

`queries.ts`

```js
import {getFirestore, QuerySnapshot} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
const db = getFirestore();

function getUsers() {
    return db.collection("User").get() as Promise<QuerySnapshot<User>>;
}

async function getAllItems(userId: string) {
    return db.collection("User").doc(userId).collection("Items").get() as Promise<QuerySnapshot<Item>>;
}

// 20-30 more functions to get/set/update/create/delete
```

When I call `/getUserTotals` from the site, it'll look something like this in the Logs Explorer:

| Timestamp | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:00.000 MST | `Function execution started` |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:03.000 MST | `Function execution took 3000 ms, finished with status code: 200` |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:10.000 MST | `getUsers: 7.000s` |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:10.000 MST | `users.length 10` |
| 2023-01-05 00:02:00.000 MST | `getAllItems user0 2:00:000 (m:ss.mmm)` |
| 2023-01-05 00:04:00.000 MST | `getAllItems user1 4:00:000 (m:ss.mmm)` |
| 2023-01-05 00:06:00.000 MST | `Exception from a finished function: Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The requested snapshot version is too old.` |
| 2023-01-05 00:06:00.000 MST | `Exception from a finished function: Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The requested snapshot version is too old.` |
| 2023-01-05 00:06:00.000 MST | `Exception from a finished function: Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The requested snapshot version is too old.` |
| 2023-01-05 00:06:00.000 MST | `Exception from a finished function: Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The requested snapshot version is too old.` |
| 2023-01-05 00:06:00.000 MST | `Exception from a finished function: Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The requested snapshot version is too old.` |

I have tried rewriting the function to be recursive, and that will at least keep the snapshots from timing out, but I can only run through ~4 users before I hit the 15-minute timeout. I've also run the function back to back, so it's not a cold start (though this seems way more extreme than the single-digit seconds that I've seen with most cold start complaints) with no difference.

When I run what is essentially the same `getUserTotals` function on the website, though, it takes ~500ms and returns 800 documents for this user I'm testing. The network call shows that I'm getting about 500 Kb of data when making the call.

Am I making some critical mistake? Is this a buggy library? I'm going to continue testing and update the thread with any answers I come up with

Edit: Converting the `function.https.onRequest` to `function.https.onCall` and returning the list of results seems to have cut down the time to about 20 seconds.

This is more tolerable, but still taking an order of magnitude longer than I would want, and also doesn't extend to the cron functions. But at least workable